# Forcing images to fully load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am fairly new to web development, so please excuse my ignorance.  I'm working on a page that generates color swatches which are just small sections of high resolution images.  There are up to 70 of these swatches being generated at a single time.  My problem is that I can't get the images to fully show up on the first try, I have to call the function again to get the images to fully load.  If I set up a function that makes my swatches visible upon loading (I'm using JQuery's .load) it never triggers, I'm assuming because it never actually loads.  Is there some way to force a full load of pages with a lot of content?

```
function showswatches(section, xmlHttpObj){
    for(i=0;i<xmlHttpObj.length;i++){
        if(xmlHttpObj[i].getElementsByTagName('section')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == section){
            $('#swatches').html();
            var colors = xmlHttpObj[i].getElementsByTagName('color');
            for(j=0;j<colors.length;j++){
                $('#swatches').append('<div class="swatch">');
                $('#swatches').append('<img src='+colors[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'>');
                $('#swatches').append('</div>');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake when copying the code here.  You seem to be missing a quote. `.append('<div class="swatch">);`

Comment: Are you making 70 calls to .load?

Comment: I'm only making one call to .load, it's after appending to my swatches div and it only makes the div visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you two options -

---

#### First option -

Add a `.load()` handler to each image and only display the image once it has fully loaded (in the mean time you could possible display a loader of sorts).  If you give all your images the same class you cat attach the event to all of them at once.  For example, if all of your `<img>` elements contain the `preloadImg` class, and you place a small loader element in your `swatch` container div, you could create a handler like this -

```
$('img.preloadImg').on('load',function(){
  $(this).parent().find('loader').hide(); // hide loader
  $(this).show();  // images initially hidden
});
```

---

#### Second option -

You could preload your swatches using JavaScript so that they start loading before your entire document is loaded and jQuery fires the `document.ready` callback.  For this you can simply create an array of JavaScript `Image()` objects and give each one the appropriate `src` property.

```
var imagePaths = ['swatch1.png','swatch2.png','swatch3.png'];
var imageLoader = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<imagePaths.length;i++){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = imagePaths[i];
  imageLoader.push(img);
}
```

As soon as you create the `Image()` object and give it a `src` property, the image will start loading and this will possibly lessen your loading time becuase as I said before, the images will start loading as soon as JavaScript is available - before jQuery has loaded and even before your full HTML content is loaded.

Comment: Used your first suggestion, worked beautifully.  Thank you so much.